# JavaScript: console.log() producing numbers instead of characters

Tags: javascript, python, terminal, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

Why do I get numbers (0 through 9) for trying to print each character in the string? The string's length is 10 so am I getting the index of each letter? How can I get the characters instead? I would like to get the output that Python would provide in similar code (code for JS and Python below together with its own output). I tried this on Google Chrome's console. Code and output below:

```
strng = 'This is me';
for (var charac in strng)
{
     console.log(charac);
}
```

Output is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Python which also has the for-in format would print each character per line. And this is what I want. Code and output below from terminals iPython:

```
strng = 'This is me'

for charac in strng:
   print(charac)
```

Python output is:

```
T
h
i
s

i
s

m
e
```

Answer (score 2):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an
>   object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can
>   be executed.

Try to use the [of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement:

```
strng = 'This is me';
for (var charac of strng)
{
     console.log(charac);
}
```

Comment: Please, remove the downvote, the answer is right :).